# cat: id_pub.dsa: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-wiki

I am trying to set up an MPI cluster, following [Setting Up an MPICH2 Cluster in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) tutorial.

However, in step *7*, I execute:

```
cat id_pub.dsa >> authorized_keys
```

but I am getting:

```
cat: id_pub.dsa: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

---

Edit:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~/.ssh$ pwd
/home/gsamaras/.ssh
gsamaras@pythagoras:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Comment: From which directory you have run the command ? `pwd`?

Comment: @heemayl edited. Off-topic: Respect for Steven btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo (seriously!!) in the documentation. What it really meant is to copy the `rsa` public key to the `authorized_keys` file so that you can `ssh` using keys (no password). So the command should be:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

After digging found that the mistake was introduced in [revision 15](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster?action=recall&rev=15) while changing the key type to use from `dsa` to `rsa`.

**EDIT:** I have edited the Wiki to make it correct.

Comment: That's what I thought too, wish I could notify the creator of this great tutorial!

Comment: At the end of the tutorial, it says: "**You** can contribute to this wiki, see Wiki Guide for details ". It's talking to Moyle.

Comment: @G.Samaras Check my edit..you can edit it too..create an account at launchpad..then you can either edit or inform the author to modify the typo..

Comment: I do not know who is the author. You found the typo, not me ;) I will test it now.

Comment: @G.Samaras I have edited the Wiki ..check now